# Origin and use of  "in and among itself"

Tags: etymology, emphasis

Where does the expression *in and among itself* come from? Is it only used for emphasis compared to *in itself*?

For example,

> This would be interesting in and among itself.

Answer (score 5):

The usual expression is *In and **of** itself*, used for emphasis, so the expression in your question seems unusual.

Could it be a deliberate mistake? We need to know the context.

For example, it seems ungrammatical to say *among itself* since 'among' implies more than one member of a group -- but does 'itself' refer to a group?

Context would help ....

Comment: I've heard it in the context "This would be interesting in and among itself". It could be a mistake, but it seems it's quite common, I get a few thousand hits on Google.

Answer (score 2):

Google search results for this bring up a lot of instances where it seems that it is a corrupted form of *in and of itself* and I think this is the case in the example given by the asker of this question.

*[In and of itself](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/04/in-and-of-itself.html)* is just an emphatic form of *in itself*, meaning:

> apart from any connexion with or relation to others; absolutely

The expression *in and among itself*, although rare in published works (9 hits on google books), can have a distinct meaning of its own.  For example:

> Unstoppable, it shoved us toward that mass of steel ribbon that curled around and around **in and among itself** like a gigantically long finely sharpened double-edged sword.

Here it means something like *convoluted*.